# Istio for windows node in kubernetes cluster

Tags: windows, kubernetes, istio

I have a mixed k8s cluster.

```
Master: Linux (Centos)
Worker1: Linux (Centos)
Worker2: Windows (Windows Server 2019)
```

I need to configure istio in this cluster. Is istio currently supported in windows pods?
Is it possible?

Comment: No, see: https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/39788#issuecomment-1226352856 and https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/27893

Answer (score 0):

nope, it is not supported at the moment. Please refer to the details here.

https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/39788